# Inserting SampleActivityBase classes into my own AppCompatActivity classes

Tags: android

I have an android application. Inside the android studio application, there are a lot of working sample projects, one of them named "BluetoothChat", What I need to do is adding the "BluetoothChat" classes to my own android studio application project such that it allows me to connect from my android application to my Arduino-Uno using the HC-05 bluetooth module. The main problem is that the "MainActivity.java" file of the "BluetoothChat" project extends "SampleActivityBase" whereas the "MainActivity.java" file of my application project extends "AppCompatActivity" !!

So, when I added the "BluetoothChat" classes to my own application project, a lot of errors occur like "Cannot resolve symbol example" because of the difference between "extends AppCompatActivity" and "extends "SampleActivityBase". How can I add the 'BluetoothChat" classes to my own application project such that no errors occur due to the difference of the "extends ... " and the packages names (My package name doesn't have '.example' but in the "BluetoothChat" project there is '.example' in its package name).

Please see this picture :-
[Cannot resolve symbol 'example'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrUiC.jpg)

Comment: Just make  `SampleActivityBase` extend AppCompatActivity... The package name can be moved easily

Comment: Can you explain more? I don't think I can write "public class MainActivity extends SampleActivityBase extends AppCompatActivity" . Could you provide me more information? I didn't get it.

Comment: It's seems that you have copied the whole `MainActivity` code, just delete those lines and re-import them again using `alt+enter` on the un-resolved syntax.

Comment: No.... If the sample activity already extends AppCompatActivity, then you only need to extend the sample... Java cannot multiple extends, but you seem to think they're entirely separate classes that you need to "merge"